# Calculating $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}(\frac{23}{1-x^{23}} - \frac{31}{1-x^{31}})$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate following limit?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{23}{1-x^{23}} - \frac{31}{1-x^{31}}\right)$$

Comment: Since it's an indeterminate form, you could try using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @julien: you can apply L'Hospital twice to your rational formula for the difference.

Comment: @robjohn And it is actually quite nice. I should believe more in l'Hospital.

Comment: @julien: so fix your answer and undelete it :-)

Comment: @robjohn Done, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=1+y$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{23}{1-x^{23}}-\frac{31}{1-x^{31}}
&=\frac{23}{1-(1+23y+\frac{23\cdot22}{2\cdot1}y^2+O(y^3))}\\
&-\frac{31}{1-(1+31y+\frac{31\cdot30}{2\cdot1}y^2+O(y^3))}\\
&=-\frac1y(1-\tfrac{22}{2\cdot1}y+O(y^2))\\
&\hphantom{=}+\frac1y(1-\tfrac{30}{2\cdot1}y+O(y^2))\\
&=(\tfrac{22}{2\cdot1}-\tfrac{30}{2\cdot1})+O(y)\\
&=-4+O(y)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{23}{1-x^{23}}-\frac{31}{1-x^{31}}=-4
$$

Answer (score 3):

Afer all, l'Hospital is not a bad alternative here. And it is certainly better than my previous answer...
$$
\frac{23}{1-x^{23}}-\frac{31}{1-x^{31}}=\frac{-8+31x^{23}-23x^{31}}{(x^{23}-1)(x^{31}-1)}=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}
$$
We have
$$\lim_1 \;p=\lim_1 \;q=0.$$ 
Now $p'(x)=713(x^{22}-x^{30})$ and $p''(x)=713(22x^{21}-30x^{29})$ yield $$\lim_1\;p'=0\quad\mbox{and}\quad\lim_1 \;p''=-8\cdot 713.
$$
For $q$, we can write $q(x)=(x-1)^2r(x)$ with $r$ polynomial such that $r(1)=23\cdot 31=713$. It suffices to use $(x^n-1)=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+\ldots+1)$. Now $q'(x)=2(x-1)r(x)+(x-1)^2r'(x)$ and $q''(x)=2r(x)+(x-1)s(x)$ for some polynomial $s$. Hence
$$\lim_1\;q'=0\quad\mbox{and}\quad\lim_1 \;q''=2\cdot 713.
$$

So a two step application of l'Hospital yields
$$
\lim_1 \frac{p}{q}=\lim_1 \frac{p'}{q'}=\lim_1 \frac{p''}{q''}=\frac{-8\cdot 713}{2\cdot 713}=-4.
$$

Comment: $31x^23-23x^3\to8$ which means the numerator goes to $0$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I see that now... I let $x$ tend to $0$ above, and to $1$ below...

Comment: I hope the downvoters will rethink their decisions.

Comment: @julien there are some typos: $q(x)=(x-1)^2r(x)$ and not $q(x)=(x-1)2r(x)$. Also, do you mean "It suffices to use $(x^n-1)=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+ \ldots +1)$"? Why did this get downvoted anyway? (+1)

Comment: @IvanLoh Thanks a lot for catching these. It was downvoted because I previously proved that the limit was $-\infty$...

Answer (score 3):

Generalized form

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{m}{1-x^{m}} - \frac{n}{1-x^{n}}\right) = \frac{n-m}{2}$$

$Proof:$

$Let$ $L =   \lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{m}{1-x^{m}} - \frac{n}{1-x^{n}}\right)$

$Let x = \frac{1}{y}$

$if x\rightarrow 1$     $then$ $y\rightarrow 1$

$L =\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{m}{1-\frac{1}{y^{m}}} - \frac{n}{1-\frac{1}{y^{n}}}\right) $

$L =\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{my^{m}}{y^{m}-1} - \frac{ny^{n}}{y^{n}-1}\right)$

$L =\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{my^{m}-m+m}{y^{m}-1} - \frac{ny^{n}-n+n}{y^{n}-1}\right)$

$L =\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{(-m)(1-y^{m})+m}{y^{m}-1} - \frac{(-n)(1-y^{n})+n}{1-y^{n}}\right)$

$L =\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left((-m)+\frac{m}{y^{m}-1} - (-n)-\frac{n}{y^{n}-1}\right)$

$L =\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left((n-m)+\frac{m}{y^{m}-1} - \frac{n}{y^{n}-1}\right)$

$L =\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}(n-m)+\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(-\frac{m}{1-y^{m}} + \frac{n}{1-y^{n}}\right)$

$L =(n-m)-\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{m}{1-y^{m}} - \frac{n}{1-y^{n}}\right)$

$L =(n-m)-L$

$2L =(n-m)$

$L =\frac{(n-m)}{2}$

For above question m = 31,  n =  23

hence $L= \frac{(23-31)}{2} = (-4)$

Comment: This is neat, provided you prove that the limit actually exists.

Comment: @kalpeshmpopat: very beautiful proofs by you. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, applying L'Hopital's rule, we get:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1}{\frac{23}{1-x^{23}}-\frac{31}{1-x^{31}}}& =\lim_{x \to 1}{\frac{23(x^{23}+x^{24}+ \ldots +x^{30})-8(1+x+\ldots +x^{22})}{(1-x^{31})(1+x+ \ldots +x^{22})}} \\
& =\lim_{x \to 1}{\frac{23(23x^{22}+24x^{23}+ \ldots +30x^{29})-8(1+ 2x+\ldots +22x^{21})}{-31x^{30}(1+x+ \ldots +x^{22})+(1-x^{31})(1+2x+\ldots+22x^{21})}} \\
& =\frac{23(22(8)+\frac{8(9)}{2})-8(\frac{22(23)}{2})}{-31(23)} \\
& =-4
\end{align}